# The example newsletter has the close button underlined

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

As per the title:

[image: img]

I don't think it's by design...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed. Also the newsletter preview popup shows the new beta themed version, which we're updating to the new Skeptics design very soon.